# Delete browser Cookies using Capybara

Tags: selenium, webdriver, capybara

Deleting browser cookies using capybara is not working while i changed my code for maximizing browser window.
Initially i used following code.It works properly in case of deleting cookies

```
 browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
  Capybara.default_wait_time = 12
  browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
```

As per the requirement i need to maximize the browser window.so i changed the above code as follows and getting error in place of `browser.manage.delete_all_cookies`

```
     browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1600, 800)
    Capybara.default_wait_time = 12
    browser.manage.delete_all_cookies

'startTesting':Undefined method 'manage' for nilClass(noMethodError)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `browser` is being set to the value returned by the `resize_to` method, which based on the error message is `nil`.

You should resize the window similar to how you are deleting the cookies:

```
browser = Capybara.current_session.driver.browser
browser.manage.window.resize_to(1600, 800)
Capybara.default_wait_time = 12
browser.manage.delete_all_cookies
```

Notice that the resizing is on its own line (ie not part of the line that sets the `browser` variable).