# RSpec / Capybara tests persist cookies after moving JS to Google Tag Manager

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, google-tag-manager

I'm running some feature tests on a Cookie pop-up. The idea is to test the bahavior of it through RSpec / Capybara. This was working fine, until I decided to move the responsible JS into Google Tag Manager. It seems that from that moment onward, my cookies are persisted between Capybara sessions. Is there a way to manually reset/delete cookies between tests?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete browser Cookies using Capybara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16915116/delete-browser-cookies-using-capybara)

Comment: Not really a duplicate... as part of the question is also about why Google Tag Manager has this effect on RSpec/Capybara tests. I don't understand why there's a different behavior.